# Multiple copies of array returned by numpy.arange?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to fill a numpy array with a list of all of the x-coordinates of a pixel-based image. So basically, an `n x m` image would have `n` `1`'s, `n` `2`'s, and so on up to `n` `m`'s. Is there a simple way to fill a numpy array so that this is the case?

So far, I've thought about using `numpy.concatenate`, but that seems awfully tedious to have to come up with each array individually, and I'd be using a loop anyway, which wouldn't really help. `numpy.flatten` also comes to find, but I'd have to generate the grid first. Are there any simple solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always the **usual grid creation** function `mgrid()`:

```
x_coords = numpy.mgrid[:m, :n][0]+1  # [[1, 1, 1…], [2, 2, 2,…]]. Element 1 is instead: [[1, 2, 3,…], [1, 2, 3,…]]
```

(PS: DSM's `numpy.indices(image.shape)` is simpler if `m` and `n` are the dimensions of `image`.)

If **float coordinates** are needed, then the more general "complex step" form gives them in an efficient way

```
numpy.mgrid[:m:(m+1)*1j, :n:(n+1)*1j]  # m+1 values from 0 to m, n+1 values from 0 to n
```

(another option would be to add the float `1.` to the first form, but this would unnecessarily first create an array of integers).

If you only need one coordinate, this is a bit wasteful, though, as `mgrid[]` also creates a similar grid for the other coordinate (`mgrid[]` has two elements, here).

In some circumstances, it may be more efficient to use the **low memory footprint** `numpy.ogrid[]`, which creates in this case a  row and a column that are automatically broadcast so as to cover a 2-dimensional grid. The fact that they only use little memory can also speed things up (fewer memory accesses).

Comment: Thanks! I actually need the y-coordinates too, I just thought it would be the same for both axes!

Comment: I might use `np.indices(image_obj.shape)` instead.  (BTW, are you sure about the syntax?  Isn't `mgrid` one of the square-bracketed ones?)

Comment: np.indices sounds good for what I asked, but I also need to be able to have floats as coordinates. And yeah, mgrid is one of the square bracketed ones (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html)

Comment: @Imagine: Since "you also need to be able to have floats as coordinates", I added an efficient way of handling this case.

Comment: @EOL Thanks, also -- when should I use ogrid vs mgrid? What advantages does mgrid provide? (I can't find any documentation on the difference of sparse vs dense matrices in numpy)

Comment: @Imagine: `ogrid` is in my experience always better when "it works". For example, if calculating `x**2+y**2` on a grid, you only need to calculate `x**2` on the array of x coordinates, not for the x coordinate *at each y* (which would be wasteful, since x does not change when only y changes). You get this for free, with `ogrid`: `x, y = ogrid[:10, :10]; z = x**2+y**2` is much more efficient than the `mgrid` version, because `x` is a column/row *vector* (not a full 2D array, i.e., one of its two dimensions is 1), so `x**2` is only calculated once for each x value (10 times, with `mgrid`).

Comment: @EOL: Is there a simple way then to just multiply ogrid[:10, :10] by, say, 10, so that it behaves like a python list or tuple? (When multipled?). So essentially you have the same copy concatenated 10 times?

Comment: NumPy insists on `*10` applying to array values—this is one advantage of NumPy arrays, so no, one cannot do this. That said, as in the example I gave, broadcasting can effectively takes care of this "duplication". Maybe there is a way to use "stride tricks" to modify the `ogrid` result and make NumPy consider that the resulting array is actually larger (basically by changing its shape without using more memory, keeping a stride of 0 for the coordinate that "does not matter").

Comment: @Imagine Yes there is a simple way to 'multipy' an array like you would with a list; it uses `np.repeat` and/or `np.tile` and it's the solution I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If your `image.shape` is `(n, m)` then the x coords would be:

```
np.repeat(np.arange(m), n)
```

For example:

```
In [5]: n, m = 4, 3

In [6]: np.repeat(np.arange(m), n)
Out[6]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Of course, the y-coords would be

```
np.repeat(np.arange(n), m)
```

You might want to use `np.tile` instead for the second coordinate:

```
np.tile(np.arange(n), m)
```

Then, you'd be able to zip it and have the coords for all pixels:

```
In [9]: np.repeat(np.arange(m), n)
Out[9]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])

In [10]: np.tile(np.arange(n), m)
Out[10]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Note that this is basically a flattened version of EOL's `mgrid` solution.

Comment: Very good approach if a flat array is needed. `ndarray.reshape()` can "unflatten" the resulting arrays, if needed.

Comment: Yes, but I think @EOL's mgrid is probably better if the reshaped array is needed.  I used the flattened version since @Imagine's question implied a flattened array was desired, by calling it a `list` and by saying they'd use `np.flatten` if they could generate a grid first.

Comment: @askewchan: Thanks for your answer too -- I ended up using both! (Each for different things)